# how to add <br> tag on dom(vanilla javascript)? I can't display my next loop on new line

Tags: javascript

```
const start = document.getElementById("start");
const end = document.getElementById("end");
const btnShowEven = document.getElementById("showEven");
const display = document.getElementById("display");

const br = document.createElement("br");

btnShowEven.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  for (let i = start.value; i <= end.value; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      console.log(`${i} is an even number.`);

      display.textContent += `${i} is an even number.`;
      display.createElement += br;
    }
  }
}
```

how to add 
 tag on dom(vanilla javascript)? I can't display my next loop on new line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="text" id="start" />
    <input type="text" id="end" />
    <button id="showEven">Show even numbers</button>
    <hr />
    <p id="display"></p>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am a beginner here. Sorry. Here is my HTML file.
The output is all my loop displays in 1 line.
I wanted to display all even numbers in new line.

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: `.createElement` is a method. What is `display.createElement += br` supposed to do?

Comment: I thought it would create a new break after my loop so my next loop display will be in the new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an easy solution. Just use `innerHTML` instead of trying to create new elements.

```js
const start = document.getElementById("start");
const end = document.getElementById("end");
const btnShowEven = document.getElementById("showEven");
const display = document.getElementById("display");

const br = document.createElement("br");

btnShowEven.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  for (let i = start.value; i <= end.value; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      console.log(`${i} is an even number.`);

      display.innerHTML += `${i} is an even number.<br>`;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input value="1" id="start">
<input value="10" id="end">
<button id="showEven">Click</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! You solved my problem :))

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use `\n` to simulate a `<br>` tag. How To Use It? here's how

```
display.innerText += '${i} is an even number. \n';
```